# Как определить при распознавании голоса, является точка разделителем разрядов или дробной части?

Tags: распознавание-речи

Я делаю приложение которое использует голосовой ввод. Данные голосового ввода числа, цифры и математические знаки. Я вызываю `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` и пользуюсь результатом. Но, распознавание чисел идет не так как хотелось бы. Например число 30000 (тридцать тысяч) распознается как 30.000 и дробные числа распознаются как числа с точкой. Как я могу определить где точка служит разделителем разрядов, а где отделяет дробную часть от целой? Для меня в идеале было бы лучше выдача только словами, как в обычной речи.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: " дробные числа распознаются как числа с точкой" - что это означает в нормальных понятных словах? желательно с примерами

Comment: @Эникейщик Не, ну тут понятно. И `30000` распознаётся как `30.000` и, например, `3.14` распознаётся как `3.14`, непонятно, где настоящее число с плавающей точкой, а где тысячи отделились. Хотя странно, тысячи обычно другим знаком отделяются.

Comment: @CrazyElf Теперь понял. В вопросе непонятно описано.